# Ordering a MySQL query result based on date

Tags: php, mysql

I have a bunch of entries in a database, which I want to sort via date, but the date format looks like this `Y-m-d g:i:s`, how could I search the database via the date, and not date time?

Comment: $sql="SELECT cast(".$date." AS datetime) as sortdate FROM table order by sortdate ASC";

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's a datetime field do this for ordering

```
ORDER BY date_field ASC
```

For searching do

```
WHERE DATE(date_field) = '2010-05-08'
```

If it's a varchar type field try looking at `STR_TO_DATE` ([link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date))

Answer (score 1):

```
select * form table where date(datetime) = '2010-05-08'
```

Answer (score 0):

That's easy. Convert your dates into proper format first, which is Y-m-d h:i:s

Comment: It shows up in the database as Y-m-d h:i:s, but I am unsure on how I can go about querying the entries based on the date, and not the date time, like so: "SELECT * WHERE dateTime='2010-05-08'" for instance, is that a possibility?

Comment: @kielie if it's already in the proper format, use date() function for filtering: `WHERE date(dateTime)='2010-05-08'"` and there should be no problem with ordering already

Answer (score 0):

here is an example

```
$sql="SELECT cast(".$date." AS datetime) as sortdate FROM table order by sortdate ASC";
```

or

```
$sql="SELECT cast(DateColumnName AS datetime) as sortdate FROM table order by sortdate ASC";
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do:

```
ORDER BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(your_date)
```

your_date date needs to be converted first to Y-m-d h:i:s

Comment: poster does not mention timestamp usage in the table. Date is already Y-m-d h:i:s

Comment: if it gets converted to Y-m-d h:i:s, no need to use timestamp for ordering. Y-m-d h:i:s will be ordered all right. That's the purpose of such a format